# How can I show specific points in a smooth line curve on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I was able to create this graph

[image]

However, I want to know how I can have dots that represent the specific points, while still having this be a smooth curve.

Comment: Could you share the spreadsheet leading to this chart?

Answer (score 0):

The chart already appears to be of the 'Smooth line chart' style, so to add data points you should be able to do this in the chart editor by going to Customise/Series, then setting 'Point size' to something other than 'None'.